# Removing zeros from number

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I remove zeros (not just leading zeros, but zeros in every position) from a column containing Integers(numbers)?

For example : 0349010330 should become 349133

Answer (score 56):

Here is the solution (MySQL) for Hackerrank challenge [The Blunder](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-blunder/problem)

```
SELECT CEIL((AVG(salary)) - (AVG(REPLACE(salary, '0', '')))) AS avg_salary FROM employees;
```

- REPLACE() : used to remove 0 from salary.
- AVG() : used to calculate average salary.
- CEIL() : used to get next rounded integer.

Comment: instead of subtracting average of miscalculated salary from average of salary, you can just  average the difference i.e. avg(salary-miscalculated salary)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but replace is used on strings right, so how come its working fine on salary which is of integer type ?

Answer (score 27):

```
  REPLACE('0349010330', '0', '');
```

this also work

```
  REPLACE('0349010330', '0');
```

Comment: but i have integers and not Varchar. So if I have 3021 and 450 i want to do something like this : obtain 321 and 45 (removing the zeros) and do some operations with the new numbers like calling the average function for example... Maybe converting for int to varchar, then calling the replace function to remove the zeros and then reconvert from varchar to int might work. But i was looking for something cleaner

Comment: In your example `0349010330`  isn't a number. Just use `TO_CHAR(` to convert number to string

Comment: @ArLi91 . . . (1) The use of leading zeros in your question suggests that the representation is really strings.  (2) It will work anyway, because `REPLACE()` will convert the first argument to a string (although you might want to convert back to a number).

Comment: as Gordon say oracle has some Implicit conversion. Check the examples [**HERE**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm)

Comment: for the leading zeros it's my error. I want to remove the zeros inside the number and like you say there are no leading zeros for the numbers in sql.

Answer (score 10):

No need to convert it into string to use replace

**MySQL solution**

```
SELECT CEIL(AVG(SALARY)-AVG(REPLACE(SALARY,"0",""))) FROM EMPLOYEES ;
```

Answer (score 7):

Oracle/PLSQL

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(TO_CHAR(0349010330),'0','')) FROM DUAL;
```

MySQL

```
SELECT CONVERT(REPLACE(STR(0349010330),'0',''),INTEGER) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 5):

[HackerRank Problem link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-blunder/problem)

Solution Here ->

```
`SELECT ROUND(AVG(SALARY)-AVG(TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(TO_CHAR(SALARY),'0')))+.5,0) FROM EMPLOYEES;`
```

Comment: This is only for Oracle. Not supported in MySQL for the same problem.

Comment: Reason we have added 0.5 to the difference of both the averages is that question asks us to round it to the next integer.

Answer (score 5):

[HakerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-blunder/problem?utm_campaign=challenge-recommendation&utm_medium=email&utm_source=30-day-campaign) solution for SQL Server

```
SELECT CEILING(AVG(SALARY))- CEILING(AVG(CAST(REPLACE(SALARY,'0','')AS INT))) +1 FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

I do not know why the '+1' in the end is needed to get the correct answer.

Comment: +1 is needed since avg values usually need to consider the decimal points. Better solution would be to calculate avg as float and then convert it back to int for final difference.

Answer (score 2):

MYSQL:

REPLACE('0349010330', '0', '')

This will replace all the Os in the string with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:
TO_NUMBER(REPLACE('0349010330',0))

Answer (score 1):

HackerRank Mysql Solution  https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-blunder/problem

```
SELECT CEIL((AVG(SALARY))-(AVG(REPLACE(SALARY,'0','')))) FROM EMPLOYEES
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-blunder/problem

For Mysql, Please run below query

```
select ceil(Avg(Salary) - Avg(CAST(Replace(CAST(Salary as char(1000)),'0','') as unsigned))) from EMPLOYEES
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer

replace(salary,0)

A question similar to this found in hackerrank..blunder problem

select ceil(avg(salary)- avg(replace(salary,0))) from employees;

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need `to_number( replace( to_char(x), '0', '' ) )`
Instead you can simply type

> `replace(x, '0')`

and the casting is applyed automaticaly.
Also, you do not have to specify 0 to be empty `replace(x, '0', '')` cause `replace()` by default removes the first value if you do not specify its alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REPLACE in Oracle but remember to convert the result to number because REPLACE returns CHAR result.

```
select to_number(replace(1001,0,'')) from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer using MySQL for Hackerrank problem:

```
SELECT round(avg(salary),0)-round(avg(replace(salary,'0','')),0) from EMPLOYEES;
```

you can use:

```
replace(Column_Name,'0','')
```

the above given query to remove 0 from the given integer type input

Comment: Kindly format your code and also mention how it differs from other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    avg(salary) - avg(convert(integer, replace(salary,'0', ''))) + 1 
from employees
```

This is the answer

Comment: Please Format your code and also if would be great if you can explain it

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for removing 0 in any number.

```
replace('0349010330', '0', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL, as @[hrshd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63019129/7049131) has mentioned, his answer was:

```
SELECT CEILING(AVG(SALARY))- CEILING(AVG(CAST(REPLACE(SALARY,'0','')AS 
INT))) +1 FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

The above problem of adding +1 would not occur when both values are of the same datatype. So, a possible solution could be:

```
select ceiling( avg(cast(Salary as real)) - 
avg(cast(replace(Salary,0,'') as real)) )
from EMPLOYEES;
```

While answering the original question, in MS SQL it is:

1. Perform string replace operation with Replace() function.
2. Cast it to number i.e.int, real, etc. as required.

`cast( replace(a_number,0,'') as real )`

Answer (score -1):

HackerRank Solution https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-blunder/problem

in SQL Server

`SELECT CAST(CEILING (AVG(CAST(SALARY AS float)) - AVG(CAST(REPLACE(salary, '0', '')AS float) ) ) as int) FROM EMPLOYEES;`

Here, the actual average salary comes out to be 4046.75
and miscalculated avg salary comes out as 1794.5
Hence the difference 2252.25, which when rounded up is 2253.0,
but the hackerrank solution expects it as int,
so we need to again cast it back to int.

Comment: The question asks how to remove zeros from an number, but this appears to be for strings. There is a lot of fluff in this solution, and doesn't really answer the question as it was asked.

Comment: In response to j1mbl3s,
Since others have also answered for the hackerrank solution, and this solution might help someone who came here to figure out the hackerrank solution(which is very much related to the question asked).
  
Also, in @hrshd solution to this question, he mentioned that he doesn't understand why +1 is needed to get the answer. 
That is why i provided the whole solution and clarification to the hackerrank problem in SQL server.
I think if j1mbl3s will read the hackerrank problem statement once, this solution will make a lot more sense to you.

Comment: The question has been answered as it was asked multiple times. Your answer may be a solution to the HackerRank problem - of which there are multiple here - but it does not offer any new insight to this SO question.

Comment: If you would see, there are multiple solutions for Mysql, but there was only 1 solution in SQL server prior to this by @hrshd, that too was confusing as he mentioned in his solution that he doesn't know why +1 is needed. This solution explained the whole solution in detail. So it did provide new insights to this question according to me and could be helpful to others as well.